# Confused by module exports/requires

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, require, module.exports

I am working on a piece where I am basically refactoring existing code. I have two files: index and server. My index is:

```
const md5File = require('md5-file');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const ignoreStyles = require('ignore-styles');
const register = ignoreStyles.default;
const extensions = ['.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.svg'];
...
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/\/(build|node_modules)\//],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    'dynamic-import-node',
    'react-loadable/babel'
  ]
});
// Now that the nonsense is over... load up the server entry point
require('./server');
```

My server is like:

```
import path from 'path';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
...
const main = async () => {
  // tell React Loadable to load all required assets
  await Loadable.preloadAll();

  process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  const server = fastify(config.fastify);
  server.register(require('./routes'), config);
  server.register(fastifyStatic, {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')
  });
  if (require.main === module) {
    // called directly i.e. $ node index.js
    const address = await server.listen(config.address);
    // start listening - ROCK AND ROLL!
    server.log.info(`Server running at: ${address}`);
  } else {
    // required as a module => executed on aws lambda
    module.exports = server;
  }
};
main();
```

The server should run a REST service when executed locally, and export the server instance for the `inject` method. This way a proxy can attach to it when running under AWS Lambda.

I used the same setup before, multiple times. Only the two pieces were in the same file eg the server was inside the index. A single file version works fine - `require.main` comparison tells the program how it is running and `module.exports` exposes the server instance [`server`] with the needed `inject` method when running under Lambda and runs the REST service with a direct invocation.

However, since I need to import `react-loadable` this time, I split the files in two pieces.

Now, I probably need to figure out how the code is running inside `index.js` as `server.js` is not being invoked directly then pass it to the server. It is probably not too difficult.

My main problem is that when if I do `console.log(require('./server'))` from index, it prints `{}`. While the server instance is created successfully, and the `inject()` is present; I am somehow unable to export it from the server.js file and import into index.js correctly, and therefore [re-]export it from index.js for the proxy to attach.

Obviously, I am doing something incorrectly. To me, seems that my require does not have the server instance because the instance gets created after the require finished. Since my main() is async, it is plausible.
What is the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that your `main()` function in ./server.js is `async` and you're defining `module.exports` from within that asynchronous function. Second, you're calling `require('./server.js')` from ./index.js without waiting for the asynchronous work to finish. Node resolves `require()`-d modules as a blank object immediately (that's the `{}` you're getting), and then extends the object when any async or cyclic material becomes available. So that's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Which solutions will or will not fit your use case will depend on the details of how your AWS/direct invocation is supposed to work. Here's a suggestion:

```js
const md5File = require('md5-file');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const ignoreStyles = require('ignore-styles');
const register = ignoreStyles.default;
const extensions = ['.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.svg'];
// ...
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/\/(build|node_modules)\//],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    'dynamic-import-node',
    'react-loadable/babel'
  ]
});

process.env.serverRunLocally = require.main === module;

// Now that the nonsense is over... load up the server entry point
require('./server').then(listen => listen());
```

```js
import path from 'path';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
// ...
const main = async () => {
  // tell React Loadable to load all required assets
  await Loadable.preloadAll();

  process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  const server = fastify(config.fastify);
  server.register(require('./routes'), config);
  server.register(fastifyStatic, {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')
  });
  if (process.env.serverRunLocally) {
    // called directly i.e. $ node index.js
    return () => {
       const address = await server.listen(config.address);
       // start listening - ROCK AND ROLL!
       server.log.info(`Server running at: ${address}`);
    }
  } else {
    // required as a module => executed on aws lambda
    return server;
  }
};

module.exports = main();
```

Comment: `server => server()` is not working. I am getting a "server is not a function" error, but I believe that you are generally right. Thank you. this is the direction I am have been thinking as well. Your tweaks are definitely helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: I changed your version to: ```.then(server => {
  console.log('server.inject:', server.inject);
  module.exports = server;
});``` and that works locally. I get `server.inject: [Function: inject]`, yet from lambda logs, I see `app.inject is not a function`.

Comment: I just posted a new version using `process.env` to record whether index was run directly. Try it and let me know.

Comment: `listen => listen()` or `server => server()` won't work. For some reason, I am having a problem with an environmental variable version, which you submitted. However, short-circuited version works to a point. Your modification get be server instance inside index when I do `.then(server => server)` without `()`. However, when I do: const app = require('./index'); console.log(app); - it prints: `{}`. Nothing inside app, now. :)

Comment: `listen => listen()` isn't working because the `if (process.env.serv...)` condition is not coming back true, owing to the environment variable not working for you, for some reason. When that conditional branch gets executed, the value that is resolved will be a function, and `listen => listen()` will work fine. You could replace `process.env` with `global` to test this hypothesis.